# latexdiff breaking \frac

Tags: amsmath, latexdiff

I have equations that I will to show the difference. Unfortunately, they contain \frac. Even at --math-markup=1, those equations get broken up. Is there any way to resolve this? For example I have:

```
\begin{equation}
0.5  = \frac {1} {2}
\end{equation}
```

Change it to:

```
\begin{equation}
0.3  = \frac {10} {30}
\end{equation}
```

and I get:

```
\DIFdelbegin \MATHBLOCKdisplaymath{
\DIFdel{0.5  = \frac }{\DIFdel{1}} {\DIFdel{2}}
}
%DIFAUXCMD
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \begin{equation}
\DIFadd{0.3  = \frac }{\DIFadd{10}} {\DIFadd{30}}
\end{equation}
\DIFaddend
```

which gives me:

```
l.40 \DIFdel{0.5  = \frac }
                           {\DIFdel{1}} {\DIFdel{2}}
? 
Runaway argument?
```

I tried --config "MATHENV=equation" which gives me:

```
\DIFdelbegin \MATHBLOCKdisplaymath{
\DIFdel{0.5  = \frac }{\DIFdel{1}} {\DIFdel{2}}
}
%DIFAUXCMD
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \begin{equation}
\DIFadd{0.3  = \frac }{\DIFadd{10}} {\DIFadd{30}}
\end{equation}
\DIFaddend
```

when compiling:
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    l.39 \DIFdelbegin \MATHBLOCKdisplaymath
                                           {
    ? 
    ! Missing { inserted.

Comment: I ran latexdiff on the two fragments you showed and did not get the output that you show, I got `\begin{equation}
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{0.5  }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{0.3  }\DIFaddend = \frac {\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{1}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{10}\DIFaddend } {\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{2}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{30}\DIFaddend }
\end{equation}`

Comment: with which version of latexdiff?

Comment: I want with " --math-markup=1" because if I do not use this, equations get garbled up.

Comment: I used whatever came with texlive. 2015 can't check now, on tablet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is caused by the spaces between the \frac command and its arguments. 
You can use option `--allow-spaces`, which will ignore spaces between commands their arguments (as recognised by the curly braces). This can have side-effects, though, as sometimes this option can cause inappropriate association if a block occurs after an argumentless command.

Comment: Or download the current bleeding edge version from the latexdiff github page which has some special magic for \frac commands (will be included in version 1.1.1 and upwards)

Answer (score 0):

I also created a Perl script to handle those:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use strict;
use warnings;

my $inBlockDel=0;
my $inBlockAdd=0;

open(FILE,$ARGV[0]) or die "cannot open ".$ARGV[0];
while(my $line = <FILE>){
  chomp($line);
  if($line =~ /^\\DIFdelbegin \%DIFDELCMD < \\begin{equation}/){
    print " \\begin{displaymath}\n \\DIFdel{";

    $inBlockDel=1;
  }elsif($inBlockDel>0 &&
     $line =~ /^\%DIFDELCMD < \\end{equation}/){
    print "";

    $inBlockDel=0;
    print "} \\end{displaymath} \n";

  }elsif($inBlockDel!=0 ){

    if($line =~ /^\%DIFDELCMD/){
        print " ".substr($line,12)." \n";
    }else{
      print " ".$line." \n";
    }


    $inBlockDel+=1;
  }elsif($line =~ /^\\DIFdelend \\DIFaddbegin \\begin{equation}/){
    $inBlockAdd=1;


    print "\\DIFaddbegin\n\\begin{equation} \\DIFadd{  \n";
  }elsif($inBlockAdd>0 &&
     $line =~ /^\\end{equation}/){
    print " } \\end{equation} \n";
    $inBlockAdd=0;
  }elsif($inBlockAdd!=0 ){
    if($inBlockAdd==1){
      print " ".$line." \n";
    }else{
      print " ".$line." \n";
    }
    $inBlockAdd+=1;
  }else{
    print $line."\n";
  }


}
close(FILE);
```